# How do I do an if else statement that loops over an array of strings?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

I am basically writing a virtual zoo. I have an animal class which contains an array called eats which contains strings of foods. I have other classes, such as lion and tiger which extend my animal class. Within these classes I have specified what food they eat as this is unique for each animal. For example, a lion eats steak and celery. I have now been asked to create a canEat() method in my animal class which basically returns true if that particular animal can eat that food. How would I go about doing this?

Here is my animal class

```
public abstract class Animal {
    String[] eats = new String[] {"steak", "celery", "fish", "fruit"};

    public boolean canEat() {

    }
}
```

and here is how I specify what each specific animal can eat in their respected class

```
public class Lion extends Animal {
     public Lion (String[] eats) {
          super(new String[] {"steak", "celery"});
     }
}
```

Thanks in advance, I hope I explained this clearly

Comment: `public boolean canEat() {` needs to be past something before you can make a check, something like `public boolean canEat(String food) {`

Answer (score 2):

Define the `canEat` method as follows:

```
public boolean canEat(String food) {
    return Arrays.asList(eats).contains(food);
}
```

Here is how you can use it:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Lion lion = new Lion(new String[] {"steak", "meat", "otherFood"});

    System.out.println("Can the lion eat steak ? " + lion.canEat("steak"));
    // System.out: Can the lion eat steak ? true

    System.out.println("Can the lion eat meat loaf ? " + lion.canEat("meat loaf"));
    // System.out: Can the lion eat meat loaf ? false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your array to List of Strings as `List<String>` and then check if list `contains` the food (passed as argument to canEat). Modify your canEat to as follow

```
public boolean canEat(String food) {
    List<String> eatsList = Arrays.asList(eats); 
    //if(eatsList.contains(food)) { 
    //   return true; 
    //} else {
    //  return false; 
    //}

    //as pointed out in comments would do exactly as above four lines of code
    return eatsList.contains(food); 
}
```

Then when you create object you invoke `canEat()` and pass it the food as argument.

```
lion.canEat("fish");
```

Comment: A bit redundant don't you think? :)

Comment: I know but, I wasn't sure if he is allowed to use List or not. That's why I showed him how to convert array to List.

Comment: Not about the list part, but about the return :D Look again :p

Comment: @Raf No, they mean you could just do `return eatsList.contains(food)` the `if-else` statement is redundant

Comment: Now I see what you are talking about. I am getting there slowly. Thanks for pointing out though.

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to solve this, using a for loop:

```
public boolean canEat(String food) {
    for (int i = 0; i < eats.length; i++) {
        if (eats[i].equals(food))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change one of your classes slightly, for example, you could do something like...

```
public abstract class Animal {
    String[] eats;

    public Animal(String[] canEat) {
        eats = canEat;
    }

    public boolean canEat(String food) {
        boolean canEat = false;
        for (String eatiable :eats) {
            if (eatiable.equals(food)) {
                canEat = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return canEat;
    }
}
```

Equally, you could make `canEat` `abstract` and make the child classes deal with it.

This does a case-sensitive comparison, if you need to a case-insensitive  comparison, you could use `eatiable.equalsIgnoresCase(food)` instead

Answer (score 0):

So full answer can be

```
public abstract class Animal {
    private String[] eats;

public Animal(String[] eats) {
    this.eats = eats;
}

public boolean canEat(String food) {
    return Arrays.asList(eats).contains(food);
}
```

}

```
public class Lion extends Animal {
     public Lion (String[] eats) {
          super(eats);
     }
}
```